Elastic maximum shards open best practics
does anyone knows how can i solve

Error: Validation Failed: 1: this action would add [2] shards, but this cluster currently has [3000]/[3000] maximum normal shards open

i know elasticsearch suggest some default solutions like re-index indices or delete prevues indices but i have two problem one i cant remove indices because elastic now is live on productions and data are important, second indices are more than million some of them are two huge i cant calculate how much time does it take to reindex completed and elastic be available for end users of course i cant add more data nodes because elastic clustering deployed with docker on three seperate servers so if i want to add more nodes  i have to restart entire container so it's impossible.I looking for some kind of solutions that solve my problem with lowest cost. I have to add this elastic deployed on ecommerce website with more that millions indexes, and this not my job just I have to maintains to increase performance of elastics


i cant add more data nodes because elastic clustering deployed with docker on three seperate servers so if i want to add more nodes i have to restart entire container

I'm curious why you'd have to restart your cluster. The whole purpose of Elasticsearch is to be able to scale your cluster horizontally as needed by adding more nodes.
Nonetheless, while you prepare for adding another node, you can still increase the limit of the maximum number of shards allowed per node.
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.max_shards_per_node": 3500
  }
}

Since the default limit is 1000 and you're already at 3000, it means someone already increased that limit once. So you should be careful. Just know that this comes with a risk as each shard consumes resources, so adding more shards to the node will put even more pressure on them, which is why you should really consider adding more nodes.
